# Dynamic widget sizing in Kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I have a custom widget `Message` that consists of a `TextInput`, a `Button` and a `Label`. The `TextInput` is meant to be uneditable, its purpose is just to display text. But I have trouble resizing it to fit the text. I've seen someone asking about dynamic height, he's got an answer to do something like `wdg.height = (len(wdg._lines) + 1) * wdg.line_height`. And while this does work perfectly for height, I'm not sure how to implement something similar for width. Maybe there is some kind of a `line_width` property? I think of maybe multiplying the font_size and the longest line but the size taken up by different letters isn't consistent and I don't see a way to predict the wrapping, so that is an issue. Are there any better variants?
Here is a piece of my code that defines the widget:

```
Builder.load_string('''
<Message>:
    FloatLayout:
        pos: root.pos
        width: self.width
        height: self.height
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: 0, 0, 0, 1
            RoundedRectangle:
                pos: root.pos
                size: self.size
            Color:
                rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
            RoundedRectangle:
                pos: root.x + 1, root.y + 1
                size: self.width - 2, self.height - 2

        Button:
            id: bt
            pos: root.pos
            size: self.size
            background_normal: ''
            background_down: ''
            background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
            on_press: root.test()
            MyTextInput:
                pos: root.pos
                size: bt.size
                id: msg
                background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
                readonly: True
                text: str(msg)
                cursor_color: 0, 0, 0, 0

        Label:
            x: root.x + 65
            y: root.y - 15
            size: 40, 2
            id: time
            color: 0, 0, 0, 1
            font_size: 10
''')

class Message(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Message, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def test(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("Touch received")
```

And a function in the `build` method that is responsible for creation of these widgets:

```
def msg_in(*args, **kwargs):
    global pr_msg_y, msg_stack
    msg = tx1_main.text.strip("\n ")
    if msg not in string.whitespace:
        msg_stack.append(Message())  

        time = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M")
        msg_stack[-1].ids['time'].text = time

        msg_stack[-1].ids['msg'].text = msg

        msg_stack[-1].width = 500
        msg_stack[-1].ids['msg'].height = (len(msg_stack[-1].ids['msg']._lines) + 1) * msg_stack[-1].ids['msg'].line_height

        for i in msg_stack[-1].children:
            i.height = (len(msg_stack[-1].ids['msg']._lines) + 1) * msg_stack[-1].ids['msg'].line_height
        msg_stack[-1].y = sv1_main.height - 5 - pr_msg_y - msg_stack[-1].height
        msg_stack[-1].x = 5

        tx1_main.text = ''

        msg_float.add_widget(msg_stack[-1])
        pr_msg_y += msg_stack[-1].height + 5
```

where `tx1_main` is where I get the text from (`TextInput`) and `sv1_main` is a `ScrollView` that displays a `FloatLayout` (`msg_float`) that displays these message widgets.

Comment: Is there any special reason for using `TextInput` when it should only display some text? Maybe you'd do better if you used `Label`. With Label you could use `texture_size` for example.

Comment: @KeyWeeUsr Yes, I want the text to be selectable, that's why I didn't go for labels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, there is a way. Apparently, `TextInput` has a protected property `_lines_labels`, which is a list of textures to perhaps represent the lines. Those textures have size, so I can access it to find the maximum and adjust my widget's size appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `TextInput` has a property `minimum_height`. You can just add the following to kv to make any `TextInput` the right height:

```
size_hint_y: None
height: self.minimum_height
```

As for width, there is no equivalent. There's not generally any need for this (whereas `minimum_height` is commonly needed, particularly for single-line inputs). If your purpose is to allow the text to be copied to the clipboard, I'd suggest just using a `Label` and putting a small `Button` next to it that copies the entire text to the clipboard. For `Label`, you can size it like so:

```
size_hint: None, None
size: self.texture_size
```

Even better, you can also add padding:

```
size_hint: None, None
height: self.texture_size[1] + dp(8)
width: self.texture_size[0] + dp(8)
```

Comment: The labels are not an option for me, the ability to copy the whole text is not enough, but that doesn't matter. Perhaps I could address Kivy devs to maybe try to implement something like that? But for now, I think I'll stick to multiplying. Thanks for help